# Importing header file in html file is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a header.html and header.js files because I want to use the same header through my webpages.
In header.js file,  on window load I want it to console.log("header file loaded").
I also have index.html and index.js file for my homepage. In index.js, on window load I want it to console.log("index file loaded")

I called header.html in index.html file, in order to import the header for the homepage. This works fine.
based on js files the console output should

> header file loaded
>
> index file loaded

The problem I am having is that
it seems like header.js and index.js cannot work simultaneously
only the last referenced file gets outputed in the console

for example this format

```
 <script src="js/header.js"></script>
 <script src="js/index.js"></script>
```

will output

> index file loaded

and this

```
  <script src="js/index.js"></script>
  <script src="js/header.js"></script>
```

will output

> header file loaded

I use the code to import header.html in index.html

```
  <head>
    <div data-include="header"></div>
   
  </head>


  <body>
       <script>
  $(function(){
    var includes = $('[data-include]');
    jQuery.each(includes, function(){
      var file = $(this).data('include') + '.html';
      $(this).load(file);
    });
  });
</script>

</body>
```

this is the content of both js file

```
   function retrieveInfo(data) {

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
        var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
        return firebase.database().ref('/Sellers/' + userId).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
         
            console.log(userId)
            console.log("index file loaded")

        });
    }
  })
  }
```

what am I doing wrong and how can I fix it to have both js file called?

Comment: can i see your code ?

Comment: So the `console.log` of `index file loaded` and  `header file loaded` in the files `js/index.js` and `js/header.js`? If you always see only one of the console log if you include  both of your script using the `script` tag and always only the first one, then the reason is most  an error that is thrown after the log, or in an other way related to the content of these files. Do you see any error message in the console? How does the content of `js/index.js` and `js/header.js` look like?

Comment: @t.niese I have updated the question with the file content. That is all that is in both file

Comment: So in both files the function is named `retrieveInfo`? And after the two `script` elements that load `index` and `header` you have a script that class the `retrieveInfo` function?

Comment: @t.niese yes, the only difference is that js/header.js statement says console.log("header file loaded")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it in a wrong way, [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is used for loading HTML contents. You should be using [`.getScript()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/), to load the js and execute it.

According to docs:

**.load()**

> Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element.

**.getScript()**

> Load a JavaScript file from the server using a GET HTTP request, then execute it.

Here is an example for using getScript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: "script",
    success: function() {
         alert("script loaded");
    }
});
```

In your case it would be:

```
$(function(){
    var includes = $('[data-include]');
    jQuery.each(includes, function(){
        var JS = $(this).data('include') + '.js';
        var file = $(this).data('include') + '.html';
        $(this).load(file);
        $.ajax({
            url: JS,
            dataType: "script",
            success: function() {
                alert(file + " loaded");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: please can provide an example of how to use .getScript()

Comment: `var file = $(this).data('include') + '.html';`  will result in e.g. `header.html` as value for `file`, so you will try to load a `html` document using `dataType: "script"`

Comment: it's not displaying my header as it previously did. your answer appears to be loading just the header.js file and not the header.html file

Comment: it works but I'm only getting one console output. whichever js file I reference last in index.html is the one that gets output to the console

Comment: @learner101 You can not have multiple functions with same name in the same scope, and that is why you are getting only one message in console. Add a `console.log('message')` at the very start of your js files(not in any function) and it will work just fine

Comment: I can't believe it, it works. So it was working initially and I didn't know. thank you buddy